# Aspose .Doc or .Docx convert to Single-Page Tiff

Tags: tiff, imaging, aspose

How can one use Aspose to convert .Doc or .Docx into a Single-Page Tiff?  I know how to make a multi-page tiff but i'm wanting to have separate files for each page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following 'Aspose.Words for .NET' code to save each page in your Word document to single page TIFF image:

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx");

ImageSaveOptions options = new ImageSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Tiff);
options.PageCount = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < doc.PageCount; i++)
{
    options.PageIndex = i;
    doc.Save(MyDir + "Out" + i + ".tiff", options);
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: This will convert a .Docx to a Multipage TIFF with the filename sequence being the number of pages in the document.  It will attempt to create the same Multipage TIFF the same number of pages in the document.  This won't work...but it was one of my very first attempts, so not a bad guess!

Comment: Well, the code above will produce 5 separate TIFF images if your Word document has 5 pages. Did you manage to solve the problem on your side or are you still in need of assistance? I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.